# How to crawl google web images

Tags: image, web-crawler

I would like to crawl the results returned by google web images. Are there tools provided by google? I am building an object recognition system that needs training examples for various topics.

Comment: If you scroll to the top of the Image API page, you will see that it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful to you, as Google has deprecated their search API:

> Google Custom Search enables you to search over a website or a
>   collection of websites. Harness the power of Google to create a search
>   engine tailored to your needs and interests, and present the results
>   in your website. Your custom search engine can prioritize or restrict
>   search results based on websites you specify.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Image API of google for this.
Example:

```
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=stackoverflow";

// sendRequest
// note how referer is set manually
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, /* Enter the URL of your site here */);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// now, process the JSON string
$json = json_decode($body);
// now have some fun with the results...
```

More information: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_snippets_php

Comment: Scroll to the top of that page, and you will see that it has been deprecated.

Comment: it is not said that what is deprecated... For me, the code works very well

Comment: "The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to upgrade to the Custom Search API, which now supports image search." - Google  https://developers.google.com/image-search/

Answer (score 0):

```
package GoogleImageDownload;

import java.io.*
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.w3c.dom.*

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Chrome/44.0.2403.157";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
                    String url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=isch&q=test";

    http.sendGet(url);

    System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
    //http.sendPost();

}

// HTTP GET request
private void sendGet(String url) throws Exception {


    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

        //print result
        String Html2Xml = light_html2xml.Html2Xml(response.toString());
        Document convertStringToDocument = DocumentObjectClass.convertStringToDocument(Html2Xml);
        NodeList Images = convertStringToDocument.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for(int i = 0;i<Images.getLength();i++)
        {
             Node node= Images.item(i);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
             {   Element elem = (Element) node;

                 if(Integer.parseInt(elem.getAttribute("height").replace("px", ""))>10&&Integer.parseInt(elem.getAttribute("width").replace("px", ""))>10)
                 {
                     System.out.println(elem.getAttribute("src"));
                     try{
                     saveImage(elem.getAttribute("src"),String.valueOf(i));
                     }
                     catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}

                 }
             }
        }
                    NodeList href = convertStringToDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(int i = 0;i<href.getLength();i++)
        {
             Node node= href.item(i);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
             {   Element elem = (Element) node;

                 if(elem.getAttribute("href")!=null)
                 {

                     try{
                         sendGet(elem.getAttribute("href"));                         }
                     catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}

                 }
             }
        }            

}


public static void saveImage(String imageUrl,String name) throws IOException {
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
String fileName = url.getFile();

String destName = new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name+".jpg";
System.out.println(destName);

    OutputStream os;
        try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
            os = new FileOutputStream(destName);
            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
}   }
os.close();
}
}
```